# $http.get 404 of JSON file using .then

Tags: angularjs, json, http, get

I was running through a set of Angular videos on YouTube and found out that .success is deprecated, and to use .then instead. I get a 404 error using both a .json file and a .txt file. I tried using .txt as people mentioned browsers don't allow local files to access other local files.

This is the $http request I have at the moment

```
$http.get('data/ninjas.txt').then(function(response) {
       // Success!!!
        $scope.ninjas = response.data;
    });
```

This is my .json file which is valid through JSONLint

```
[{
    "name": "Yoshi",
    "belt": "green",
    "rate": 50,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/yoshi.png"
}, {
    "name": "Crystal",
    "belt": "yellow",
    "rate": 30,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/crystal.png"
}, {
    "name": "Ryu",
    "belt": "orange",
    "rate": 10,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/ryu.png"
}, {
    "name": "Shaun",
    "belt": "black",
    "rate": 1000,
    "available": true,
    "thumb": "content/img/shaun.png"
}]
```

I tried testing using both httpster and using Brackets built in live preview. I get a 404 error, but the file does for sure exist as you can see in the image

[image]

If it helps, this is my whole app.js file

```
var myNinjaApp = angular.module('myNinjaApp', ['ngRoute']);

myNinjaApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
        .when('/directory', {
        templateUrl: 'views/directory.html',
        controller: 'NinjaController'
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}]);

myNinjaApp.controller('NinjaController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.removeNinja = function(ninja){
        var removedNinja = $scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
        $scope.ninjas.splice(removedNinja, 1)
    };

    $scope.addNinja = function(){
        $scope.ninjas.push({
            name: $scope.newninja.name,
            belt: $scope.newninja.belt,
            rate: parseInt($scope.newninja.rate),
            available: true
        }); 

        $scope.newninja.name = "";
        $scope.newninja.belt = "";
        $scope.newninja.rate = "";
    };

    $http.get('data/ninjas.txt').then(function(response) {
       // Success!!!
        $scope.ninjas = response.data;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Why isn't the ninjas.txt file a ninjas.json file ?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby I have tried both and both 404. I read on another question that when running local browsers/localhosts have issues interpreting JSON, but making the file a .txt or .html file for some reason works. I have a .json file and have tried that as well. Both 404.

Comment: Is your path relative to index.html or app.js file ? Try using 'app/data/ninjas.json'

Comment: @JoeriShoeby changing the path to what you suggested worked! Is there a reason why that path worked though? I tried it using .json and the .txt file and both worked. Thanks! Just curious why it had to be the path relative to the index.html and not relative to the app.js

Comment: Because browser makes relative requests based on current page url, not script source

Comment: @charlietfl Gotcha. So when building angular js apps, pathing should be relative to the index.html or pathing should be directly from the sever path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the answer complete,

Your root of your application is 'index.html', and because Angular is running within 'index.html', all files you load in your files are relative to your 'index.html'.

An example of that is seen in your route configuration, where your templates are loaded starting at 'views/*', which is a child folder of your 'index.html'

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer!

Comment: not entirely accurate when using htm5Mode routing. Is relative to  url path. Also `views` is sibling of index

Comment: You're definently right, but as you can see he isn't using that.

Answer (score 0):

```
myNinjaApp.controller('NinjaController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        url: "data/ninjas.json",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $scope.ninjas = resp;
    }, function (resp) {
       // bla bla bal
    });

    $scope.removeNinja = function (ninja) {
        var removeNinja = $scope.ninjas.indexOf(ninja);
        $scope.ninjas.splice(removeNinja, 1);
    }

    $scope.addNinja = function () {
        $scope.ninjas.push({
            name: $scope.newninja.name,
            belt: $scope.newninja.belt,
            rate: parseInt($scope.newninja.rate),
            available: true
        });
        $scope.newninja.name = "";
        $scope.newninja.belt = "";
        $scope.newninja.rate = "";
    };

    $scope.removeAll = function () {
        $scope.ninjas = [];
    };

    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname; 
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    }

}]);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

As for all who struggle getting not an array with net ninjas and the code above  you now get  the whole HTTP response under data not the JSON file itself you need to get the data property of the request so like this:

```
$http.get('app/Data/ninja.json').then(function(data) {
  $scope.ninjas = data.data;
}, function() {

});
```